# Stylus - How to achieve a parametric transform?

Tags: css, stylus

I have a `ul` with N `li` inside. I want to rotate each `li` by `360/N` degrees, so that they form a wheel.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/zpXEXP?editors=1100)

I have tried many syntaxes in Stylus to achieve that, but I always get the same error :

> expected "ident" or "string", got "unit 360"

For instance :

```
n=8
for i in (1..n)
    li:nth-child({i})
        transform rotate( {360/i}deg ) // expected "ident" or "string", got "unit 360"
```

or

```
n=8
for i in (1..n)
    li:nth-child({i})
        transform rotate( {360/i + 'deg'} ) // expected "ident" or "string", got "unit 360"
```

or

```
n=8
rotation = 0deg
for i in (1..n)
    li:nth-child({i})
        transform rotate( rotation )
    rotation = rotation + {360/i} + "deg" // expected "ident" or "string", got "unit 360"
```

or

```
n=8
rotation = 0deg
for i in (1..n)
    li:nth-child({i})
        transform rotate( rotation )
    rotation += {360/i + "deg"} // expected "ident" or "string", got "unit 360"
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier:

```
n=8
for i in (1..n)
    li:nth-child({i})
        transform rotate(360/i deg)
```

Comment: Oh no way XD The simplest solution is often the one we don't try. Thanks! But why is it not `:nth-child(i)` then?? It's not logical